# How to read the json file after skippinf few lines in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a json file whose contents is as follow:-

```
[
{"time":"56990","device_id":"1","kwh":"279.4"},
{"time":"60590","device_id":"1","kwh":"289.4"},
{"time":"64190","device_id":"1","kwh":"299.4"},
{"time":"67790","device_id":"1","kwh":"319.4"},
]
```

Now I want to read this file one line at a time using `seek` and `tell` methods in python. I tried this but it shows an error saying `not able to decode`. I actually want to read the json file after every 15 mins or so from that pointer where it was last read. 
This is what I have tried.

```
last_pointer = 0
with open (FILENAME) as f:
    f.seek(last_pointer)
    raw_data = json.load(f)    // this raw_data should load json starting from the last pointer.
    .....process something.........
    last_position = f.tell()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json   
import time

with open ('dat') as f:
  line = f.readline()
  while line:
    try:
      raw_data = json.loads(line.strip().strip(','))
      print (raw_data)
      time.sleep(15*60)
    except ValueError:
      pass
    line = f.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is arranged in lines exactly as shown, you can construct an ad-hoc solution by reading lines from the file one by one, trimming the trailing comma, and feeding the result to `json.loads`. But perhaps the better variant would be to use a streaming parser like [`ijson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/).

Comment: The structure of my json file will be like this only for sure, but according to my logic I need to parse `x` number of lines from the json file at one time and `y` number of lines at other times. How do I do it? Can you please provide with an example?

Comment: Read about `ijson`. Cant see any use of it in this problem.

Comment: "I need to parse x number of lines from the json file at one time and y number of lines at other times" — that's exactly what ``ijson`` does behind the scenes. It does not read the whole file/stream at once. The example is right there at the start of the documentation.